executing binary files on android targetSdkVersion>28 raise Permission denied
I have an application that creates a ssh connection tunnel for traffic forwarding. It's working perfectly on targetSdkVersion 28 and below, but on targetSdkVersion > 28 when running (executing) the following commands (when running binary files), it raises error 126 OR Permission denied.
The binary execution output stores some file descriptor. Somebody says that this error raised because of W^X violation.
I have embedded the binary files into apk (the files are located in app/src/main/assets/bin and then after installation, these files are copied to /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin and set the permission of the files to 755 as below:
String BASE = "/data/data/*package_name*/myfiles";
String BASE_BIN = "/bin"
Util.runChainFireCommand("chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/busybox;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/korkscrew;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/redsocks;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/iptables;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/ssh;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/sshpass;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/tun2socks;" +
     "chmod 755 " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/pdnsd",true);
    }

after file is copied, when I execute the commands as below:
    public static int runChainFireCommand(String command, boolean root, boolean fork, boolean ask4retval) {

        final int[] retval = new int[1];
        if(fork)
        {
            final String myCommand = command;
            final boolean myRoot = root;
            final boolean myAsk4retval = ask4retval;
            Thread t = new Thread(){
                @Override
                public void run(){
                    if(myRoot) {
                        Shell.run("su", new String[]{myCommand}, new String[]{}, true);
                        retval[0] = 0;
                    }
                    else {
                        if(myAsk4retval) {
                            try {
                                retval[0] = Integer.parseInt(Shell.run("sh", new String[]{myCommand + "; echo $?"}, new String[]{}, false).get(0));
                            } catch (Exception e) {
                                retval[0] = 0;
                            }
                        } else {
                            Shell.run("sh", new String[]{myCommand}, new String[]{}, false);
                            retval[0] = 0;
                        }
                    }
                }
            };
            t.start();
            try {
                t.join();
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
        else {
            if(root) {
                Shell.run("su", new String[]{command}, new String[]{}, false);
                retval[0] = 0;
            }
            else {
                if(ask4retval) {
                    try {
                        retval[0] = Integer.parseInt((Shell.run("sh", new String[]{command + "; echo $?"}, new String[]{}, false)).get(0));
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        retval[0] = 0;
                    }
                } else {
                    Shell.run("sh", new String[]{command + "; echo $?"}, new String[]{}, false);
                    retval[0] = 0;
                }
            }
        }
        return retval[0];
    }

ssh_return_val = runChainFireCommand(
                            ((key_switch && !enc_ssh_key) ? "" : BASE + BASE_BIN + "/sshpass -p \"" + password_text + "\" ")
                                    + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/ssh " + server_text + " -p " + port_number + " -l " + user_text
                                    + " -NT -g -D " + Util.localSocksPort + (dns_switch?" -L 127.0.0.1:8163:"+dns_server+":53":"")
                                    + forward_string
                                    + (key_switch ? " -i \"" + BASE + "/id_rsa\"" : "")
                                    + (compress ? " -C" : "")
                                    + " -o \"ProxyCommand " + BASE + BASE_BIN + "/korkscrew"
                                    + (iptables_switch ? "" : " --ancillaryfile " + BASE + "/sshfd_file")
                                    + (proxy ? " --proxyhost " + proxy_host
                                    + " --proxyport " + proxy_port + " --desthost %h --destport %p"
                                    + " --headerfile " + BASE + "/header_file" + "\""
                                    : " --directconnection --desthost %h --destport %p\"")
                                    + " -o \"KeepAlive yes\" -o \"ServerAliveInterval 15\""
                                    + " -o \"StrictHostKeyChecking=no\" -o \"GlobalKnownHostsFile=/dev/null\"", false, true);
                }


this is logcat:
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/sshpass: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH-] 126
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH+] /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox killall -9 korkscrew;/data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox killall -9 ssh /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox killall -9 tun2socks/data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox killall pdnsd
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] START
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH+] /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox killall pdnsd; echo $?
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][C][SH%] END
[libsuperuser][O][SH*] sh: <stdin>[1]: /data/data/package_name/myfiles/bin/busybox: Permission denied
[libsuperuser][O][SH-] 126

it's said that in order to avoid W^X violation, you must embed the binary files with in APK. Now I did it, but still I get Permission denied.

The updated discussion by the Termux team (follow links in thread) but found your prior post with similar references.

I have set targetSdkVersion=28 and get APK output and run the app on android 10,11,12,13 without problem. so if the problem is android 10(as the Termux stated) why the APK works on even android 13 for me BUT NOT 14

You should clarify your post with your comment details as originally looked similar to the Termux issue. Apologies for not noticing you are using busybox so info regarding setup and if on a rooted device or not may be helpful to readers.

i use busybox, look at this: https://developer.android.com/about/versions/10/behavior-changes-10#execute-permission says i can't execute from app home directory, where else i must copy my binary files?

I link to this as your base path doesn't match: Own busybox executable in Android via apk
